# Regular Expression rule to match spaces before and after specific character

Tags: regex

I need to exctract number portion from string.

```
This is the product title 132/891 with specification in it
```

I can found the forwards slash with regex but cannot made rule to get the number portion between the spaces after it, like so:

```
132/891
This is the product title with specification in it
```

Comment: Is it always an slash inbetween the numbers? D oyou want the numbers to be seperate or always together?

Comment: What flavor are you using. It could affect the answer. Also, can you include what regex you have come up with? And what exact rules the number portion should follow. And does your result resemble what you are after? Extracting the number portion and rearrange your string?

Comment: Yes, slash is allways between numbers. I run pregreplace after that because i need the number portion elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might help you. \b matches a word boundary, means spaces, end of strings, or special characters. \d matches a single digit. \d+ mathes a number that is bigger than one digit

```
\b\d+\/\d+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/AP7TL9/1